# How to force update of ShellIconOverlays on files in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-shell

I have several ShellIconOverlays registered using the [IShellIconOverlayIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. Each of them has logic that determines if the overlay should be used or not. From what I understand, the overlays get their IsMemberOf() method called once initially for each file icon when an icon is shown by the explorer shell. It also appears that IsMemberOf() gets called if the file is renamed. But how can I grammatically force the explorer shell to update the icon on a file? I basically want to have the overlays update like they TortoiseSVN and Dropbox have their overlays update when the file status changes.